# uGUIのInputFieldで、日本語を入力できるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？(MacOS環境)

Tags: unity3d

Unity(4.6.1)を利用して、PC/Macアプリをつくっています。

アプリ内で、ユーザーに対して名前入力を促すために、UI.InputFieldを利用しているのですが、日本語が入力できない状況です。

InputFieldのOnValueChangeで、入力を検知して対応しようとも試みましたが、関数が実行されないため対策が取れていません。

基本的な設定ミス、もしくは対策などありましたら、アドバイスを頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

◯補足情報
・InputFieldの設定は、以下の設定をしています
　　"Content Type" = "Custom"
　　"Character Validation"="None"

・実行中に、日本語を入力しようとすると、文字変換前はInputField内に文字が表示されますが、確定するタイミングで、文字列が無効になっているような挙動をします。

・Inspector上で、初期値として、"テスト"などを設定しても、Editor実行後は空文字列になってしまいます。

=======================================================
※追加　2015/01/06 13:30
　InputFieldの"Line Type"を、"Multi Line NewLine"に設定したところ、
　日本語が入力できることを確認しました。"OnValueChange"も実行されます。

"OnValueChange"で、改行を無視するようにすれば対応できそうな見込みが立ってきていますが、
　よりよい方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: Windows版の4.6.1p2でCanvasを配置InputFieldを追加、補足情報の項目を設定しましたが、エディター上での実行チェックをする限りでは問題ありませんでした
UnityはMac上での開発でしょうか？
作成環境やIMEの情報なども書くと回答を得やすいと思います

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。
開発環境は、MacBookPro(OSX10.10.1)。
IMEは、Google日本語入力を利用しています。
ことえりにも変えてみましたが、わたしの環境では、だめでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Windows環境で同じプロジェクトを試したところ、UnityEditor、実行ファイル共に、日本語の入力が可能なことを確認しました。
Mac環境で発生する現象のようなので、Unityの問題と判断して、報告します。
ただし、公式対応には時間がかかると思われますので、対応方法があれば、情報がほしいところです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.9.5   / Unity 4.6.1f1 の環境では

Asset Store の UI Samples

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/jp/#!/content/25468

の UI.InputFieldに、ことえり での日本語入力は問題ありませんでした。

---

追記

Mac OS X 10.10 で IME が改訂されたことと関係した現象とも考えられます。

Unity 4.6.0 での不具合として登録されている

628352 JAPANESE CHARACTERS ARE NOT DISPLAYED WHEN THE NEW INPUTFIELD ON MAC

は解決されており、以下との重複だとすると

646989 A NEWLINE CHARACTER GETS ADDED TO THE INPUT FIELD AFTER/IF IT WAS RESELECTED AND REACTIVATED FROM WITHIN AN ONENDEDIT CALLBACK

Patch 4.6.1p2　にて修正されている可能性があります。

http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

注意：以下のような報告あり。

「Unity4.6.1p2が公開されておりますが
こちらでUnityWebPlayerのビルドを行った場合、
公開されている最新のPlayerでは要求バージョンを満たしておらず再生する事ができません。」

Comment: OS X Yosemite から日本語入力エンジン「ことえり」を終了し、新しいMeCabを使った「日本語IM」を採用したことなどが関係していそうですね。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。

こちらでも、UIサンプルを動かしました。（シーン:Controls）
"ことえり"にした状態でInputFieldに、文字入力しようとしましたが、文字変換を行うためEnterを押した時点で、空文字列になってしまいました。

Comment: シーン:Controls で　ことえり のローマ字入力で文字変換は”スペース” キーで Enter では文字変換は実行されない設定ですが、問題なく動作しています。(ことえり でなくMeCabのYosemiteにそのうちに移行したいと思っていますがまだ 10.9 のままです)

Comment: 不具合として似たような現象は報告されているようです。
JAPANESE CHARACTERS ARE NOT DISPLAYED WHEN THE NEW INPUTFIELD ON MAC
http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/japanese-characters-are-not-displayed-when-the-new-inputfield-on-mac

Comment: Enterは、文字変換を決定する際に押しています。
誤解を招く文章になってしまい、申し訳ございません。

Comment: 私の環境では確認できないのですが
Patch 4.6.1p2　で修正されているかもしれませんのでPatchをまだ適用されていないのであれば適用してみるといいかもしれません。
http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/a-newline-character-gets-added-to-the-input-field-after-slash-if-it-was-reselected-and-reactivated-from-within-an-onendedit-callback

http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Comment: 646989
A NEWLINE CHARACTER GETS ADDED TO THE INPUT FIELD AFTER/IF IT WAS RESELECTED AND REACTIVATED FROM WITHIN AN ONENDEDIT CALLBACK
Status: Fixed in Unity 4.6.2
http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/a-newline-character-gets-added-to-the-input-field-after-slash-if-it-was-reselected-and-reactivated-from-within-an-onendedit-callback